# Why is my selected profile picture being replaced by my Gravatar or Identicon?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-picture, gravatar

As I was editing some questions, it appeared like "Edited just now by Imran Ali Khan", but my profile picture is showing the default Identicon picture. I checked my profile, and my picture is uploaded and selected, and now I was checked my previous activities, and the default Identicon is showing everywhere. In the site header, however, my selected profile picture is showing.

For example: [SQL Server Insert if not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971680/sql-server-insert-if-not-exist)

Is this happening with everyone? Or is it just me that's facing this problem?

Comment: Can confirm. Am having the same issue; I first noticed it in the "Edited By" user badge here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30582414/microsoft-edge-window-open-not-honoring-width-height-and-opens-in-background

Comment: I can confirm that I am having the same issue too (and even posted a separate question [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298278/profile-picture-shows-up-differently-in-qa-pages) before realizing you had already asked one). However I see the issue only for some users. For example refer to the screenshot in my question where the other user's profile pic shows up perfectly fine.

Comment: Yah, you are right harry, i also notice that, I was planning to add screen shorts, but i am facing problem to there is no option here (in Ask Question) to post Image