# Profile picture shows up differently in Q&A pages

Tags: support

From today morning, I am noticing that the profile picture on my User page does not match with the profile picture that is displayed on the Question and Answer pages.

I am able to see and reproduce this behavior in all the Question and Answer pages for my profile but it doesn't seem to be happening for other users.

**Screenshot from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441122/shape-with-a-slanted-side-responsive) Question page:**

[image]

**Screenshot from my user page:**

[image]

I can see this behavior for my profile both in Meta and main site. I have not changed my profile picture anytime recently.

Comment: I swear that I had not seen that question before I posted this one. Did not even appear in the suggested items box in Ask Questions page.

Comment: I don't really understand the downvote here to be honest. Yes, there is a dupe available but it was not posted a long time before this one and it certainly did not appear in the searches before creating the question. Are people intending to say that I should remove this question just because it is a dupe? I have already close voted my own question but have not deleted it because dupes are sign posts.